# SU : Permission denied /bin/sh

Tags: linux, sudo, su

I added a new user in system:

```
$ useradd new_user
```

When I try to switch from `root` to `new_user`, I get this error:

```
$ su new_user
permission denied /bin/sh
$grep new_user /etc/passwd
new_user:x:2001:4001::/home/new_user:/bin/sh
$/bin/ls -ld /bin
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan  1 00:07 /bin
$/bin/ls -ld /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Jan  1 00:07 /bin/sh -> /etc/alternatives/sh
$/bin/ls -ld /etc/alternatives/sh
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Jan  1 00:07 /etc/alternatives/sh -> /bin/bash
$/bin/ls -ld /bin/bash
-r-xr-x---    1 root     shell       700076 May 27  2014 /bin/bash
```

Comment: This may belong on the superuser stack exchange website.

Comment: What system are you on? How did you switch to the new user? su newuser? Does your user appear in /etc/passwd?

Comment: Also, please use backticks for in-line terminal formatting; it makes things much easier to read.

Comment: Please edit your question to include (a) the result of `grep new_user /etc/passwd`, (b) the result of `/bin/ls -ld /bin`, and (c) the result of `/bin/ls -l /bin/sh`.